# How to determine the sample size for a Confirmatory Factor Analysis CFA

Tags: measurement, methodology, statistics, sampling

I'm in the process of developing a scale. Overall, my question is how do I determine how many participants to include in my sample for the first Confirmatory Factor Analysis procedure? More specifically, can you tell me about different approaches to determining the sample size, such as power analyses or Monte Carol simulations, and research that backs this up.

I've done some research. It seems that the general rule of thumb is that you should have approximately 10 participants per item.

Comment: While there is nothing *wrong* with asking this question on this site, I think you're vastly more likely to get a good answer if you ask on stats.SE.

Comment: Thank you Bryan, I'll give it a shot here first given the overlap.